# Creating 4D numpy array by repeating values from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

I have a 2D numpy array, say `array1` with values. `array1` is of dimensions 2x4. I want to create a 4D numpy array `array2` with dimensions 20x20x2x4 and I wish to replicate the array `array1` to get this array.

That is, if `array1` was

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I want

```
array2[0, 0] = array1
array2[0, 1] = array1
array2[0, 2] = array1
array2[0, 3] = array1
# etc.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer.

```
array2[:, :, :, :] = array1.copy()
```

this should work fine

Comment: If you are using initialized `array2`, you don't need that copy().

Comment: and you don't need all the `:, :, :, :`, one simple `:` would also work (by broadcasting).

Comment: Thank you Divakar and MSeifert for the suggestions.

Comment: Going with this copying method would be in-efficient as you are making that unnecessary copy.

Comment: @Divakar what do you mean unneccesary copy? How does this copy function work?

Comment: @Gautam That copy made with `array1.copy()` is un-necessary. You are assigned values into `array2`, which could directly be fed from `array1` itself, rather than making a copy of `array1` and then feeding from it. Thus, you could simply do : `array2[:, :, :, :] = array1`.

Comment: @Divakar ok. So they make an internal copy of the array in the memory and that's why it takes time. Just like copy in windows

Answer (score 4):

One approach with initialization -

```
array2 = np.empty((20,20) + array1.shape,dtype=array1.dtype)
array2[:] = array1
```

Runtime test -

```
In [400]: array1 = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,4)

In [401]: array1
Out[401]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

# @MSeifert's soln
In [402]: %timeit np.tile(array1, (20, 20, 1, 1))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.01 µs per loop

# Proposed soln in this post
In [403]: %timeit initialization_based(array1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.11 µs per loop

# @MSeifert's soln for READONLY-view
In [406]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(array1, (20, 20, 2, 4))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 µs per loop
```

Comment: you don't need the trailing `,` in your tuple `(20, 20,)` - that's only needed for one-element-tuples. :)

Comment: The timings should be treated with care (I get roughly the same results for small arrays). Because as far as I know is `np.broadcast_to` a constant time operation.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy ways:

[`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
array2 = np.broadcast_to(array1, (20, 20, 2, 4))  # array2 is a READONLY-view
```

and [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
array2 = np.tile(array1, (20, 20, 1, 1))          # array2 is a normal numpy array
```

---

If you don't want to modify your `array2` then `np.broadcast_to` should be really fast and simple. Otherwise `np.tile` or assigning to a new allocated array (see [`Divakar`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488633/5393381)) should be preferred.